# Angular calendar: Custom css added in beforeWeekViewRender event is being removed on resize event

Tags: angular, angular-calendar

On resize event, custom css class is being removed and on mouseup, the beforeWeekViewRender is triggered and in consecuence, the custom css re added. This happend in week view.

I can found the root cause of the issue. In day view works fine.

`In .html

`

```
<mwl-calendar-week-view *ngSwitchCase="CalendarView.Week"
                          (beforeViewRender)="beforeWeekViewRender($event)"
                          [viewDate]="viewDate"
                          [events]="calendarEvents"
                          [refresh]="refresh"
                          (eventClicked)="handleEvent('Clicked', 
                          $event.event)"
                          (eventTimesChanged)="eventTimesChanged($event)"
                          [hourSegmentTemplate]="weekViewHourSegmentTemplate"
                          >
</mwl-calendar-week-view>
```

`

`In .ts`

`

```
public eventTimesChanged({
    event,
    newStart,
    newEnd
  }: CalendarEventTimesChangedEvent): void {
    let disabledArea = false;
    if (!this.checkIfSegmentIsDisabled(newStart, 2)) {
      event.start = newStart;
    } else {
      disabledArea = true;
    }
    if (!this.checkIfSegmentIsDisabled(newEnd, 2)) {
      event.end = newEnd;
    } else {
      disabledArea = true;
    }
    if (!disabledArea)
      this.handleEvent('Dropped or resized', event);
    else alert("Excedio el limite");
    this.refresh.next();
  }
```

`

During resize event, the css should not be removed